# Does a Java EE container automatically close an injected EntityManagerFactory?

Tags: jakarta-ee, containers, entitymanager, java-ee-7

Say that I have this code in a @Stateless Enterprise JavaBean:

```
@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;
```

Will the Java EE container automatically close my `EntityManagerFactory` sooner or later?

### What the specs say

The [Java Persistence specification, version 2.1](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr338/index.html) says the following on page 338:

> When the application has finished using the entity manager factory,
>   and/or at application shutdown, the application should close the
>   entity manager factory.

Okay, so that is pretty straight forward. I have to close the factory.

However, since I injected the factory in the first place, I'm a bit nervous calling the close() method all by myself. What if the container is no smarter than trying to reuse a closed factory in the next bean that wants a factory? Also, I don't like to add a lot of plumbing to hook my own logic into what happens or not at application shutdown. Moreover, it just smells bad that I didn't open/create the factory, yet my code is responsible for closing it. Surely the massive pile of Java EE specifications has something more to tell me about this issue?

Well.. **no**. The examples I've seen in the JPA 2.1 and [EJB 3.2](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr345/index.html) specification that inject a factory do not close it explicitly. The examples do close it only if they explicitly create a factory by means of [`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/Persistence.html#createEntityManagerFactory(java.lang.String)) (see JPA 2.1 specification, pages 345 and 355).

The only talk about the container's responsibility that I've seen comes from the JPA 2.1 specification page 356:

> [..] the container is required to support third-party persistence
>   providers, and in this case the container must use the
>   PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory method to
>   create the entity manager factory and the EntityManagerFactory.close
>   method to destroy the entity manager factory prior to shutdown (if it
>   has not been previously closed by the application).

Here it says that the container do have the responsibility to close the factory. But what makes me hardly believe in this last quote is that the example/quote clearly talked about a very particular use case when the container uses a "third-party persistence provider".

For me, the topic becomes even more confusing if I read the chapter on *Persistence Unit References* in the EJB 3.2 specification that begins on page 286. In here, there is not a word on who bears the responsibility of closing the entity manager factory - me or the container.

My conclusion is that I should, or rather must be, safe by copying the examples used in the specifications. Meaning that I don't have to close the factory explicitly. What is mainly confusing to me though is the first quote I used from the JPA specification that clearly says I have to close the factory!

What is your opinion? Have I missed anything?

Comment: Since the EMF is created for you by the container, it should close it for you, too. I'm having a hard time finding references, though.

Comment: My reasoning goes the same.

Comment: I know it's not an answer, but usually you inject the `EntityManager` and not the `EntityManagerFactory`.

Comment: I need an application managed EntityManager for a particular use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `EntityManagerFactory` is created by your container, it is responsible for its lifecycle (and thus closing it). There is only one `EMF`, so closing it would make no sense except on the end of your applications lifecycle. From the [JPA 2.1 spec](https://java.net/projects/jpa-spec/downloads) section 9.1:

> [...]
>
> The EntityManagerFactory instance obtained as a result will be used by
>   the container to create container-managed entity managers. **Only one
>   EntityManagerFactory is permitted to be created for each deployed
>   persistence unit configuration.** Any number of EntityManager instances
>   may be created from a given factory.

You are, however, responsible for closing your `EntityManager` if you decide to manage it by yourself via the injected `EMF`.

Comment: You are quoting the specification that talks about persistence contexts and the entity manager. Not a persistence unit, the entity manager factory. They are two different things.

Comment: I don't think so. 7.8.1 explicitely mentions that application managed persistence contexts need to close the EMF via EntityManagerFactory.close(), while 7.8.2 says the container manages the persistence context transparently.

Comment: 7.8.1 does not say that. 7.8.2 does talk about the persistence context, that is, the entity manager. Again, I talk about the persistence unit, the entity manager factory. 7.8.2 also says that the entity manager might be pooled, and in that case, he will never be closed by the container. I reason exactly like you do, that it should be safe to say that the container manages the life cycle of an injected entity manager factory too. What is strange is the first quote in my question that cites the specification saying we need to close the factory explicitly.

Comment: The first quote is not strange. That's just a general statement that the EMF should always be closed if the application (container or unmanaged) is done using it. It's not directly related to your application in a managed environment.

Comment: Before my quote starts, the specification says: "The EntityManagerFactory interface is used by the application to obtain an application-managed entity manager". So the context is an injected isntance and the "application" must be my code; my code being responsible for closing the factory. Where in the specification does it say who bears the responsibility of closing the factory? Your edited answer bears a significant quote of which one must *conclude* that it is the containers responsibility. I still argue that the quote I used says the opposite, unfortunately.

Comment: I can follow your reasoning, but considering my experience (I have never seen managed code closing EMF) the spec indicates that the application must not close the EMF in a managed environment. Have you tried it after all?